# Failed to connect azure iot hub with esp8266 using azure-iot-arduino library

Tags: c++, ssl, arduino, esp8266, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to connect to azure iot hub with esp8266 using azure-iot-arduino library: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino

I've faced several problems doing that:

1) AzureIoTUtility library. File **esp82266/sample_init.cpp** function `configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");` doesn't work - after that I'm getting message *"Fetching NTP epoch time failed! Waiting 2 seconds to retry."* again and again.
It is possible to fix that with `configTime( "GMT", "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov" );` function instead of `configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");`
Or using **initTime** function from samd directory.

2) AzureIoTUtility library. File **adapters/sslClient_arduino.cpp.** function `sslClient.connect(ip, port);` in `sslClient_connect(uint32_t ipAddress, uint16_t port)` returns 0 status.
I think it`s some problem with sertificate that is used in the library.
I've tried esp32 example and desktop example (c sdk) and they both work well.

The main goal of my project is to use the arduino iot sdk with **Arduino MKRZERO** and **Ethernet** modure. 
I'm trying to integrate Ethernet library into arduino iot sdk.
For ssl connection I've tried **ArduinoBearSSL** library and **SSLClient** library and had the same result.

Comment: Have you tried opening firewall ports or trying it on a different network? Something can be blocking you to reach to pool.ntp.org or time.nist.gov servers.

Comment: I haven`t tried that, but the same code works on esp32

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue using -DUSE_BALTIMORE_CERT flag
but problem 1 is still exists

Comment: Check this issue, looks the same: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino-protocol-mqtt/issues/1